TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEnabled' of null, js engine: hermes
I'm trying to integrate a Zebra barcode scanner for a React Native application running on a Zebra mobile device. However, I'm encountering several issues that I need help with.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEnabled' of null
When attempting to use the useZebraScanner hook and accessing the setEnabled function, I'm encountering this error:

const { setEnabled } = useZebraScanner(handleScan);
2. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
I'm getting the Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 TypeScript error when defining the handleScan function:
const handleScan = useCallback((code: string, scannerId: number) => {   console.log(Scanned: ${code});   setBarcode(code); }, []);

3. Block-scoped variable 'handleScan' used before its declaration.ts(2448)Even after defining the handleScan function, I'm still encountering this error:
const [barcode, setBarcode] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const { setEnabled } = useZebraScanner(handleScan);

  const handleScan = useCallback((code: string, scannerId: number) => {
    console.log(`Scanned: ${code}`);
    setBarcode(code);
  }, []);

  const onPullTriggerScanning = useCallback(() => {
    if (setEnabled) {
      setEnabled(true);
    } else {
      console.error('setEnabled is not defined.');
    }
  }, [setEnabled]);

  const onReleaseTriggerScanning = useCallback(() => {
    if (setEnabled) {
      setEnabled(false);
    } else {
      console.error('setEnabled is not defined.');
    }
  }, [setEnabled]);

https://github.com/intellidev1991/react-native-scanner-zebra-enhanced

Your first error is most likely happening due to the second error.
The second error is caused by you not passing in the 2 required arguments for useZebraScanner. As shown in their documentation, it should have 2: useZebraScanner(onScan, onEvent).
Your last error is a result of you using handleScan before you define it, which is the case. Move your handleScan definition above your useZebraScanner call so you can reference it.
